# Is there a shortcut in IntelliJ that allows you to create a boilerplate HTML file like in VSCode?

Tags: intellij-idea

In VSCode you can basically type '!' then hit enter and you get a boilerplate HTML document. I love that feature and I wonder if IntelliJ has the same. If it doesn't how could I make it myself? I've tried macros, but it's not instantaneous it types every character one after the other. I've searched for their html shortcuts in keymap and didn't find anything of that sort. Their doc is not helpful either. Do you guys have any idea or hack on how to do that?

Comment: does IntelliJ has snippets or Emmet

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom Html file template(https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-file-and-code-templates.html) from File | Settings/Preferences | Editor | File and Code Templates.